# события в javascript

Tags: javascript

как можно отловить событие клик по видео, дабл клик по видео. Нужно сделать играть/пауза по клику и полноэкранный режим - дабл клик. использую через тег video
Iframe не могу использовать из-за его особенностей

Comment: `click`, `dblclick`

Comment: а можно поподробней?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант, при двойном клике, паралельно срабатывает 2-ва одинарных :

```js
document.querySelector('#video').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('click');
});

document.querySelector('#video').addEventListener('dblclick', function() {
  console.log('dblclick');
});
```

```css
#video {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="video"></div>
```

[enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880608/prevent-click-event-from-firing-when-dblclick-event-fires) - тут нашел вариант решения для етой проблемы :

```js
document.querySelector('#video').addEventListener('click', xorClick);

var pendingClick = 0;

function xorClick(e) {
  // kill any pending single clicks
  if (pendingClick) {
    clearTimeout(pendingClick);
    pendingClick = 0;
  }

  switch (e.detail) {
    case 1:
      pendingClick = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('single click action here');
      }, 500); // should match OS multi-click speed
      break;
    case 2:
      console.log('double click action here');
      break;
    default:
      console.log('higher multi-click actions can be added as needed');
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
#video {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="video"></div>
```

Comment: Благодарю! то что нужно!!!