# dblclick отменяет click. Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток!

Есть такой код:

```
line.click(function () {
// Скрывает детей line
})

line.dblclick(function () {
// Редактирует line
})
```

Когда хочу отредактировать `line` срабатывает `click` дважды. Выглядит убого, дети скрываются, затем появляются.

Как сделать так, чтобы при `dblclick` не срабатывал `click`? Поставить функции на другие события нельзя

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/718667/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-javascript/718679#718679)

Comment: Супер! То, что нужно!